# Cannot fix "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have three vars so it seems occur compiler, when i try to check does time has passed or not.
I have

```
let currentDate = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let loginUpdateDate = sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate
let nextDateLoginUpdate = currentDate - loginUpdateDate
```

but when i try to do this, i'm getting

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

It simple operation with Int but seems it overloading for the compiler.
Im doing this to use if statements later

```
if nextDateLoginUpdate < 300
```

full code is:

```
struct editProfileView: View {
    @State var loadImage : Image? = nil
    @State var source : UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    @EnvironmentObject var sessionStore : SessionStore
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var bio:String = ""
    @Binding var showEditProfile:Bool
    @State var showEditPassword = false
    //    var user = User?
    @State var loadingView = false
    
    //image picker
    @State var showChoose = false
    @State var image: Image? = nil
    @State var showImagePicker = false
    @State var imageData : Data? = nil
    @State private var offsetValue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var body: some View {

            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    //переменные для даты и проверки последующего обновления данных на странице
                    //let loginUpdateDate = sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate
                    //let nextDateLoginUpdate = currentDate - loginUpdateDate
                    Group {
                        Group {
                            VStack {
                                    Group {
                                        //аватарка
                                        //если картинка не выбрана
                                        if (self.image == nil) {
                                            if (self.sessionStore.userSession?.profileImageUrl == nil) {
                                                ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                                                    Image("user-placeholder")
                                                        .resizable()
                                                        .scaledToFill()
                                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                    
                                                    Image(systemName: "goforward.plus").padding(5)
                                                }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                    .onTapGesture {
                                                        //выключаем если прошло меньше времени
                                                        self.showImagePicker = true
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                if (self.loadImage == nil) {
                                                    ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                                                        Image("user-placeholder")
                                                            .resizable()
                                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                            .clipShape(Circle())
                                                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                        
                                                        Image(systemName: "goforward.plus").padding(5)
                                                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                        .onTapGesture {
                                                            self.showChoose = true
                                                            //выключаем если прошло меньше времени
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                    
                                                else {
                                                    ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                                                        loadImage!
                                                            .resizable()
                                                            .scaledToFill()
                                                            .clipShape(Circle())
                                                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                        
                                                        Image(systemName: "goforward.plus").padding(5)
                                                    }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                        .onTapGesture {
                                                            self.showChoose = true
                                                            //выключаем если прошло меньше времени
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                
                                            }
                                            
                                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                                Text(name).font(.headline)
                                            }
                                            
                                            //если картинка выбрана
                                        } else {
                                            ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
                                                image! //может использовать "!" так как делаем проверку и уверены, что это не nil
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .scaledToFill()
                                                    .clipShape(Circle())
                                                
                                                Image(systemName: "goforward.plus").padding(5)
                                            }.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    //                                self.showImagePicker = true
                                                    self.showChoose = true
                                            }
                                        }
                                        
                                        HStack {
                                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("Bio:")).fontWeight(.bold)
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                        HStack {
                                            TextField(LocalizedStringKey("Bio"), text:$bio).padding(.top)
                                        }.padding(.bottom).padding(.horizontal).background(Color("textFieldBackground")).cornerRadius(10)
                                    }
                            }
                        }.padding(.horizontal).padding(.top)
                            
                        Button(action: {
                            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
                            if (currentUser != nil) {
                                self.loadingView = true
                                let id = currentUser!.uid
//                                добавить в коллекцию ниже параметры когда получитсвя везде обновлять инфо
//                                "username" : self.name, "keywords" : self.name.splitStringToArray()
                                Ref.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_USERS.document(id).updateData(["bio" : self.bio]) { (err) in
                                    //Конструкция: если err (ошибка) не nil, значит ест ьошибка и что-то пошло не так
                                    // если nil, значит все хорошо
                                    if let err = err {
                                        //делаем что-то если ошибка
                                        //например показываем надпись с сообщением об ошибке
                                        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                                        self.loadingView = false
                                    } else {
                                        self.sessionStore.userSession?.bio = self.bio
                                        //то же самое только если все получилось
                                        print("Document successfully updated")
                                        if (self.imageData == nil) {
                                            self.loadingView = false
                                            self.showEditProfile = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                //save image
                                //Если новая картинка выбрана
                                if (self.imageData != nil && self.sessionStore.userSession != nil) {
                                    //Сначала загружаем в хранилище, а затем ссылку на это фото обновляем в базе данных у пользователя
                                    let storageAvatarUserId = Ref.STORAGE_AVATAR_USERID(userId: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
                                    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                                    metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
                                    //для био было
                                    //cлушатель для обновления био
                                    self.sessionStore.userSession?.bio = self.bio
                                    //для логина - апдейт
                                    self.sessionStore.userSession?.username = self.name
                                    
                                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("update_profile_bio"), object: nil)
                                    StorageService.updateAvatar(userId: self.sessionStore.userSession!.uid, username: self.sessionStore.userSession!.username, email: self.sessionStore.userSession!.email, imageData: self.imageData!, metaData: metadata, storageAvatarRef: storageAvatarUserId, onSuccses: {url in
                                        if url != nil {
                                            self.sessionStore.userSession?.profileImageUrl = url!
                                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("update_profile_image"), object: nil)
                                            self.loadingView = false
                                            self.showEditProfile = false
                                            
                                        } else {
                                            self.loadingView = false
                                        }
                                        
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                            
                            
                        }) {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(LocalizedStringKey("Save changes")).foregroundColor(Color("ButtonFont")).fontWeight(.bold)
                                    Spacer()
                                }.padding().background(Color("ButtonBackground"))
                            
                        }.cornerRadius(5).shadow(radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10).padding()
                    }
                    
                    Group {
                        HStack {
                            if nextDateLoginUpdate < 300 {
                                Text(LocalizedStringKey("Less than a week has passed since the last login change, or the account was just created. Please wait")).foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray3)).padding(.top)
                            }
                            Text(LocalizedStringKey("User name:")).fontWeight(.bold)
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.top, 50)
                        // проверка для изменения логина
                        if nextDateLoginUpdate < 300 {
                            HStack {
                                TextField(LocalizedStringKey("Current username"), text: $name).padding(.top)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray2))
                                    .disabled(nextDateLoginUpdate < 300)
                            }.padding(.bottom).padding(.horizontal)
                            .background(Color(.systemGray5))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        } else {
                            HStack {
                                TextField(LocalizedStringKey("Current username"), text: $name).padding(.top)
                            }.padding(.bottom).padding(.horizontal).background(Color("textFieldBackground")).cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        Button(action: {
                            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
                            if (currentUser != nil) {
                                self.loadingView = true
                                let id = currentUser!.uid
//                                добавить в коллекцию ниже параметры когда получитсвя везде обновлять инфо
//                                "username" : self.name, "keywords" : self.name.splitStringToArray()
                                Ref.FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_USERS.document(id).updateData(["username" : self.name, "keywords" : self.name.splitStringToArray()]) { (err) in
                                    //Конструкция: если err (ошибка) не nil, значит ест ьошибка и что-то пошло не так
                                    // если nil, значит все хорошо
                                    if let err = err {
                                        //делаем что-то если ошибка
                                        //например показываем надпись с сообщением об ошибке
                                        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                                        self.loadingView = false
                                    } else {
                                        self.sessionStore.userSession?.username = self.name
                                        self.sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)
                                        //обновление displayname
                                        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                                        changeRequest?.displayName = self.name
                                        changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
                                            if error != nil {
                                                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                                                return
                                            } else {
                                                print("user has change his displayname to", Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        //то же самое только если все получилось
                                        print("Document successfully updated")
                                            self.loadingView = false
                                            self.showEditProfile = false
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }) {
                            if nextDateLoginUpdate < 300 {
                            HStack {
                                Spacer()
                                Text(LocalizedStringKey("Change username")).foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray6)).fontWeight(.bold)
                                Spacer()
                            }.padding(.top).padding(.bottom).background(Color(.systemGray3))
                            } else {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(LocalizedStringKey("Change username")).foregroundColor(Color("ButtonFont")).fontWeight(.bold)
                                    Spacer()
                                }.padding(.top).padding(.bottom).background(Color("ButtonBackground"))
                            }
                            
                        }.cornerRadius(5).shadow(radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10).padding(.top).disabled(nextDateLoginUpdate < 300)
                        //конец блока обновления логина
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.top)
                if self.loadingView == true {
                    VStack {
                        lottieView(filename: "loading-profile")
                    }.background(Color("textFieldBackground").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical))
                    
                }
            }.background(Color(UIColor.systemGray6).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical))
                .keyboardSensible($offsetValue).animation(.spring())
            .onTapGesture {
                closeKeyboard()
            }
                
            .onAppear() {
            let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
            if (currentUser != nil) {
                
                if (self.loadImage == nil) {
                    getImageByName(name: currentUser?.uid) { (image) in
                        if image != nil {
                            self.loadImage = image
                        }
                    }
                }
                print(currentUser!.uid, "userid")
                let id = currentUser!.uid
                Api.User.loadUserById(id: id, onSuccess: {user in
                    if (user != nil) {
                        self.bio = user!.bio
                        self.name = user!.username
                    }
                })
            } else {
                print("nil in editProfileView")
            }
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker, content: {
            ImagePicker2(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, pickedImage: self.$image, imageData: self.$imageData)
        })
            .actionSheet(isPresented: self.$showChoose, content: {
                ActionSheet(title: Text(LocalizedStringKey("Take photo")), message: Text(LocalizedStringKey("Add photo from sourse")), buttons: [
                    .default(Text(LocalizedStringKey("Upload")), action: {
                        self.source = .photoLibrary
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        //                        self.cameraViewModel.showImagePicker = true
                    }),
                    .default(Text(LocalizedStringKey("Take a photo")), action: {
                        self.source = .camera
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        //                        self.cameraViewModel.showImagePicker = true
                        //                            self.showChoose = true
                    }),
                    .cancel(Text(LocalizedStringKey("Cancel")))
                ])
            })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably it is due to huge view, try to separate its body into smaller subviews.

Comment: @Asperi maybe create function to this operation? Can it help?

Comment: Asperi is most likely right. That’s a huge view.  The more you move out of it the less you’ll run into this.  Yes, moving those 3 lines to a separate function in a separate file should fix it... but... my guess is you’ll keep running into this as you try to do more and more.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to change the first line like the below snippet code:

```
let date = Date()
let timeInterval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
let currentDate = Int(timeInterval)
```

Test this I hope it helps otherwise you have to make the other code to  smaller snippet

Comment: also getting
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions....
let date = Date()
                    let timeInterval = date.timeIntervalSince1970
                    let currentDate = Int(timeInterval)
                    let loginUpdateDate = sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate
                    let nextDateLoginUpdate = currentDate - loginUpdateDate

Comment: please post here all code for this function.

Comment: done. Have added full struct.
Also whant to say - it sometimes cause crush if i calling 
let loginUpdateDate = sessionStore.userSession!.loginUpdateDate
And i dont know how safe unwrap it. Have tryed if statesments and gurad. Thats why i trying to to another whay
Maybe you have any idea how unwrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting loginUpdateDate to int

```
let currentDate = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
if let loginUpdateDate = sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate as? Int { 
let nextDateLoginUpdate : Int = currentDate - loginUpdateDate }
```

These sort of compiler warnings happen every time Swift isn't clear what a "let" or "var" declaration's type will be before compile.

The optional chaining (if let ... as? Int { ... } ) isn't necessary, but it might be safer. Alternatively;

```
let currentDate = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let loginUpdateDate = Int(sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate)
let nextDateLoginUpdate = currentDate - loginUpdateDate
```

Edit Feb 5 2021:
Here's another idea : make sure the currentDate and the loginUpdate date are both Doubles (I believe the "timeInterval" default Type) then cast to Int after the operation so :

```
let currentDate = Double(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let loginUpdateDate = Double(sessionStore.userSession?.loginUpdateDate)
let nextDateLoginUpdate = Int(currentDate - loginUpdateDate)
```

Comment: sorry for amateurish question, (i'm stuying), where in code should to add this solutions? If i'm trying to put on front beyond var body: some View { (23 line) - it cannot find nextDateLoginUpdate "in scope, if i trying to past it without it, i again getting "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions". seems i trying to past it in wrong place in code..

Comment: Your question is fine and I guess I should have elaborated. In the first example, when loginUpdateDate succeeds to be cast to Int in the conditional code, the "next DateLoginUpdate will be in the scope of the if else statement.